# Java Reactor: Is there a way to transform Flux<Mono<T>> into Flux<T> without eager fetching?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I have a fast, but expensive producer (Spring WebClient) and a very slow subscriber. I need a way to honor backpressure throughout the chain.

During implementation I realized that flatMap, concatMap and others use eager fetching and there seems to be no possibility to disable this behavior.

Using demand in the subscriber without flatMap

```
Flux.defer(() -> Flux.range(1, 1000))
            .doOnRequest(i -> System.out.println("Requested: " + i))
            .doOnNext(v -> System.out.println("Emitted:   " + v))
            //.flatMap(Mono::just)
            .subscribe(new BaseSubscriber<Object>() {
                protected void hookOnSubscribe(final Subscription subscription) {
                    subscription.request(3);
                }

                protected void hookOnNext(final Object value) {
                    System.out.println("Received:  " + value);
                }
            });
```

.. produces:

```
Requested: 3
Emitted:   1
Received:  1
Emitted:   2
Received:  2
Emitted:   3
Received:  3
```

Using same demand with flatMap (uncommented) produces:

```
Requested: 256
Emitted:   1
Received:  1
Emitted:   2
Received:  2
Emitted:   3
Received:  3
Emitted:   4
Emitted:   5
...
Emitted:   254
Emitted:   255
Emitted:   256
```

Comment: concatMap is not eager fetching. Unless one inner-stream completes, it won't subscribe to the next stream.

Comment: I just tested it with the above code. It requests 32 items.
I could limit the number with the ```prefetch``` parameter, however in that case any demand bigger than prefetch will be split up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is an open issue for this: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1397

Anyway, I found a solution for my situation: `block()`. Keep in mind that this operation is only allowed on Threads which are not marked as "non-blocking operations only". (See also [Project Blockhound](https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound))

To recap, the issue is that at some point I have a `Flux<Mono<T>>` and `.flatMap(...)`, `.concatMap(...)`, etc. use some kind of eager fetching. The `Flux<Mono<T>>` used for testing:

```
final Flux<Mono<Integer>> monoFlux = Flux.<Mono<Integer>, Integer>generate(
() -> 0, 
(state, sink) -> {
    state += 1;
    sink.next(Mono.just(state));
    return state;
}).doOnRequest(i -> System.out.println("Requested: " + i))
  .doOnNext(v -> System.out.println("Emitted:   " + v));
```

In order to not have eager fetching, I now do a block inside a map and it works surprisingly well:

```
monoFlux.map(Mono::block)
        .subscribe(new MySubscriber<>());
```

Result:

```
Requested: 3
Emitted:   MonoJust
Received:  1
Emitted:   MonoJust
Received:  2
Emitted:   MonoJust
Received:  3
```

Comment: .flatMap has a concurrency control that allows you to have N subscribers to the upstream (generator), which will control the amount of concurrent generations being executed at a given time, so no need to block.

Also you have a nice .log() operator that does the logging for you.